# Windows to achieve 'CTRL+Shift+R' in Eclipse

Tags: windows, eclipse

I am a Java developer with Eclipse. I like the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> function in Eclipse to search a file. Is there a standalone, free and open-source application to achieve the same functionality in the Windows OS?

Comment: You can download Eclipse for Windows...?

Comment: @Matthew Adams: I think OP wants that functionality working independently of Eclipse.  If that's the case, probably that AHK (AutoHotKey) would allow him to do what he wants (by binding some key combinations to whatever 'search file' program he wants).

Answer (score 3):

Try this...

This will work on **Windows 7**

**1.** F3

**2.** Windows logo key  +F

See this link:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/keyboard-shortcuts/